# Time.timeScale doesn't work with my game and the new UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

Does anyone know why Time.timeScale isn't working for me...

```
public GameObject PauseMenu;
public GameObject Controls;

private float pausedTime = 0f;
private float unPausedTime = 1f;

public int score = 0;
public Text scoreText;

public bool isPaused;
  public void PauseFunction()
{
    TogglePauseBool();
    if (isPaused)
    {
        PauseMenu.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = pausedTime;
        Controls.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (!isPaused)
    {
        PauseMenu.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = unPausedTime;
        Controls.SetActive(true); 
    }
}

void TogglePauseBool()
{
    if (isPaused)
    {
        isPaused = false;
    }
    else
    {
        isPaused = true;
    }
}
```

The PauseFunction() is called when I tap a pause UI button.

I have almost exactly the same code for the game over and it's fired if a user triggers the OnTriggerEnter2D, the Time.timeScale works perfectly on that.

The script is attached to a emptyGameObject called "_Master".

Comment: Side note - your `TogglePauseBool` logic is simplifiable to `isPaused = !isPaused`

Comment: This line: `Time.timeScale = unPausedTime; unpaused.` should not compile. Is it a copy&paste error?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It's just where I removed the comment after pasting it in.

Comment: Did you import any plugins? Some plugins like NGUI reset the timescale to 0 all the time

Comment: No, I've added no plugins to the project. It was working perfectly before, but I lost a level when transferring my project from my Dropbox folder to my C drive. So I decided to make the script again. Since then it hasn't worked.

Comment: Can you put 1) Debug.Log at the beginning of PauseFunction to ensure that it is not called twice 2) make isPaused private so that no other code can manipulate it.

Comment: TriggerEnter and CollisionEnter are notoriously finnicky at firing multiple times on accident.  If you're using Unity 4.6's uGUI, I recommend just using the OnClick functionality of a button, instead.

Comment: I figured it out. Absoklutely silly of me.. I was forgetting to reference the script in the object. I knew it would be something easy, and silly. Thanks guys.